# Build failed with 500, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output in Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I am trying to add an extension in the jupyter lab. I go to extensions tab and click "install" on the extension. After a few seconds i get a pop up saying `Build failed with 500, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output`

[image: here is the screenshot of it]

could anyone tell me how to resolve it or find the logs related to that error atleast.

Answer (score 3):

Using terminal, try `jupyter lab build`, which will produce an output on your *AppData\Local\Temp* folder (if you are on Windows). The log file will give more info on what is causing the failure during the build.

I had the same issue and npm dependencies were the culprit. I have updated conda with `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` and and yarn with `conda install yarn` and it solved the issue for me.

Also try looking at this one [Jupyter Labs: “RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install” When Building](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288104/9157828).

Answer (score 0):

For me this was fixed by pinning down a lower version of nodejs.
`conda install -c conda-forge 'nodejs<16.14'` did the trick. My resolution steps:

1. Install an environment from scratch `conda create -c conda-forge -n <your_env_name> 'python>=3.8,<3.11' 'jupyterlab>=3.10'`
2. Then attempt a nodejs install for example `conda install -c conda-forge 'nodejs<16.14'`
3. Attempt to build with `jupyter lab build` in terminal.

It's currently May 2022. Please note versions change a lot and very fast, when you face this same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

###### On the UI (User Interface) of Jupyter Lab you see

```
Build failed with 524, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output
```

###### You open a console and run

```
jupyter lab build
```

###### Which ends with

```
An error occurred.
RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-2znox977.log
```

###### Inside the log you see

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

###### Run again

```
jupyter lab build --minimize=False
```

This completes successfully.

> Explanation:
>
> - `dev-build`: This option controls whether a `dev` or a more streamlined `production` build is used. This option will default to
>   `False` (i.e., the `production` build) for most users. However, if you
>   have any labextensions installed from local files, this option will
>   instead default to `True`. Explicitly setting `dev-build` to `False`
>   will ensure that the `production` build is used in all circumstances.
> - `minimize`: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab's overall
>   performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very
>   memory intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish
>   successfully in low-memory environments.

In my case, the VM (Virtual Machine) had 3.75GB RAM and before crashing it was using ~3GB (you can see with `htop` in another console/terminal [image below]).

[image]