# Build Failed with 500 and jupyter lab build is not working either

Tags: python, conda, yarnpkg, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I am trying to install an extension for JupyterLab, but I keep getting the "Build Failed" message. It looks like the image below:
[image: Build Failed full message]

I have tried running 'jupyter lab build' as well, but I get another error. The error message looks like the image below:
[image: terminal error message]

I tried running '--dev-build=False --minimize=False' and then rerunning 'jupyter lab build', but that isn't working either.

I finally tried updating both conda and yarn (as was recommended in this thread: [Build failed with 500, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output in Jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063986/build-failed-with-500-please-run-jupyter-lab-build-on-the-server-for-full-out)), but that isn't working either.

I have checked the log file, and it says that the 'yarn run' command isn't working, and failed with exit code 2. However, I don't know how to interpret or fix this (since yarn is already up to date for me).

Does anyone know what else I can try (I use a mac if it matters)?

Comment: I deleted my comment and edited the post (so it now contains the link where it said to update conda and yarn). I also added information about the log file now.

Comment: You also don't provide the version of JupyterLab involved? JupyterLab 3 installation of extensions is much easier and different than JupyterLab 2. If you aren't using JupyterLab 3, updating to it would be an excellent idea. Also you don't mention what extension? You may have better luck looking at the issue page for that extension.

Comment: I am using JupyterLab 3.2.1 (latest version). The extension I am trying to install is tabnine. I have searched online and found people with the same issue but without any resolution.

Comment: That extension is a kind of extension that is prebuilt and so you shouldn't need to build JupyterLab, see [here](https://github.com/codota/tabnine-jupyterlab/issues/17#issuecomment-916803971). So therefore not clear how you got to this point ? Did you install as described [here](https://github.com/codota/tabnine-jupyterlab#easy-installation) and [here](https://www.tabnine.com/install/jupyterlab)? The last link just says you run that and you are ready to go.

Comment: `exit code 2` is quite broad, could you post the log file?