# How to fix this jupyter lab build issue?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I have got an error when I run: jupyter lab build in my linux.
The error log info is as follows:
[image]

It seems caused by the nodejs version.
I tried to run conda install nodejs, but it says the nodejs is already installed.
How can I fix this problem and success to build jupyter lab? Thanks a lot for checking!

Comment: check if this one is helpful pal
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271242/jupyter-labs-runtimeerror-npm-dependencies-failed-to-install-when-building

Comment: Why are you trying to build JupyterLab in the first place? Is it because of an extension you try to install? If so, please check if they have a prebuilt version available - most extensions do not require the build step in JupyterLab 3 anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Recently I update jupyterlab and when I open it, it pops up a window saying require the build. It says: [@jupyterlab/application changed from ~3.1.17 to ~3.2.5
@jupyterlab/application-extension changed from ~3.1.17 to ~3.2.5
@jupyterlab/apputils-extension changed from ~3.1.18 to ~3.2.5
@jupyterlab/celltags-extension changed from ~3.1.17 to ~3.2.5
@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension changed from ~3.1.17 to ~3.2.5.]
There are several messages like this, and I just put some items here.

Comment: The message is incorrect - the rebuild should not be required from the end user after upgrade, unless you manually re-built it before. I would uninstall jupyterlab and install it afresh (maybe even in a new virtual environment).

Comment: Thank you! It is wired and now every time I open Jupyterlab, it will first show this message window ask me to rebuild and it never succeeds.